# Can we use the data defined in configmap as a key in deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, configmap

I have a configmap created. I have added data as a key-value pair in configmap

```
data:
  EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE: /user/app/api/config
```

I need to use this variable to set a mount path in deployment

```
-  name: config-properties-volume-mnt
   mountPath: {{ $EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE }}
```

I am getting  undefined variable "$EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE" while deploying. **I do not want to define this variable in values.yaml.** Is there a way where I can use this variable defined in configmap in deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's not possible to dynamically define any parameter on a manifest**, you have to use the Helm or Kustomize

Or else you can use the **sed** to replace the **Text** in manifest simply

You can not use this way, **configmap** and **secret** are normally to inject the variables or file into the POD not at declare step.

```
-  name: config-properties-volume-mnt
   mountPath: {{ $EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE }}
```

if you have helm chart keeping details into the `vaules.yaml` is the only option.

**Subpath method :**

You can use the subpath to achieve, with **subpath** you can use the environment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-expanded-environment

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container1
    env:
    - name: EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE
      value: /user/app/api/config
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "while [ true ]; do echo 'Hello'; sleep 10; done | tee -a /logs/hello.txt" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir1
      mountPath: /logs
      # The variable expansion uses round brackets (not curly brackets).
      subPathExpr: $(EXTERNAL_CONFIG_FILE)
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: workdir1
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/pods
```

Instead of **env** used in the above example you can use the **configmap**